# /etc/init.d/exim queue runner

Tags: exim, queue, conf

I'm having trouble getting my exim daemon to run according to the init.d script settings. The main problem is with the `QUEUE` variable. I've set it 5m to have it spawn another queue runner as needed.

Up until now it has worked, but now, when I restart exim, the command that get's issued is:

```
/usr/sbin/exim -bd -q60m
```

When it should say:

```
/usr/sbin/exim -bd -q5m
```

The first thing I did was to make sure that the `init.d/exim` script was still correct, and it is. I've looked in the exim.conf and I can't find anything there.

My only other thought is maybe cPanel is interfering with the start up because after restarting exim the script echos:

```
/usr/local/bin/cpanel/update_sa_rules is running in the background
```

I've been trying to see where the `$QUEUE` variable might be added elsewhere, but haven't seen anything yet. Would appreciate your help if you've seen this before.

Notes: This is for Exim 4.82, CentOS 5.10

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify where you set the QUEUE variable.  On a CentOS system, the exim init script typically checks for the existence of an /etc/sysconfig/exim file with configuration settings.  If it doesn't find /etc/sysconfig/exim, the init script sets some default settings, of which QUEUE is typically 1 hour.  Double check your /etc/sysconfig/exim file and make sure that there is only one QUEUE setting and that is where you are changing it.  Having said this, your system appears to be a CPanel system, which could have altered the exim init script and/or defaults in some way.

Another possibility is that **/etc/init.d/exim restart** isn't actually shutting down this exim process for some unknown reason.  Verify that it is by looking at the start time of the exim queue runner process after you do a restart.  If it's still some time or date way in the past, then the process isn't getting restarted.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. It was the **/etc/sysconfig/exim** file. I had previously set the QUEUE variable in the **/etc/init.d/exim** file, and couldn't understand why it wasn't working. That solved the problem. Thanks again!